# Using luasql-odbc with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex

I'm trying to use the luasql-odbc library with LuaLaTeX on Mac OS 10.14. I installed the library with lua 5.3 and luarocks and it is loading well with Lua. However, I am facing an issue when I try to load it with LuaLaTeX.

I used the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{luapackageloader}

\begin{document}
\begin{luacode}
package.path = "/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?;" .. package.path
package.cpath = "/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?.so;" .. package.cpath
driver = require "luasql.odbc"
\end{luacode}
\end{document}
```

And this is what I got:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021) 
 system commands enabled.
(./test-luasql-orbd.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
 L3 programming layer <2021-08-27>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)))
 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luacode/luacode.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luapackageloader/luapackageloade
r.sty) (./test-luasql-orbd.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)error loading module
 'luasql.odbc' from file './luasql/odbc.so':
    dlopen(./luasql/odbc.so, 6): Symbol not found: _lua_newuserdatauv
  Referenced from: ./luasql/odbc.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in ./luasql/odbc.so
stack traceback:
    [C]: in ?
    [C]: in local 'f'
    ...1/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic-merged.lua:398: in local 'loo
kup'
    ...1/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic-merged.lua:429: in function <
...1/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic-merged.lua:419>
    [C]: in function 'require'
    [\directlua]:3: in main chunk.
\luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }
                                                  
l.12 \end{luacode}

                 
?
```

Any idea what might solve this?

**UPDATE**

I read that in order to use Lua C libraries, lua(hb)tex should be compiled with the `--nostrip` option, which I did. I moved the luatex and luahbtex files produced to the bin directory of my TEXMF tree and then ran:

```
sudo mktexlsr
sudo fmtutil-sys --all
```

Unfortunately the issue is the same...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!